# Can I record Google+ Huddle chat messages?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-huddles

I thought they have being saved at Gmail chats like google-talk. But I was wrong.
How can I record Google+ Huddle messages? Saving at gmail will be best option.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to do this. Maybe suggest it on the google forums?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this but you can take screenshots of the chat and save it like that. There are a lot of screenshot apps on the Market, some require root though.